# Проблема с импортом, React

Tags: reactjs

Недавно начал изучение фреймворка React для добавления его на страницу, начал с создания компонентов, импортировал один компонент в App.js, который в свою очередь является корневым компонентом и используется в index.js.
Но проблема возникла там, где я её вообще не ожидал - при открытии страницы в консоли браузера вылезает ошибка "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at index.js:1:1)". Ссылка на сам импорт библиотеки React: "import React from 'react';"
Я понимаю, что компилятор как будто бы не видит библиотеку React, но я не понимаю, как сделать её "видимой".

Заранее скажу, что все пакеты предустановлены корректно. Пробовал создать react приложение командной "npx create-react-app /*название проекта*/" - оно работает исправно, без ошибок.

UPD: дополню, что я не могу импортировать другие существующие файлы в проекте в том числе.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `type: "module"` в ваш package.json

Comment: @SwaD, к сожалению, не помогло. Добавлял type во все места package, даже в package-lock нашёл type, попробовал изменить - не помогло.